# Is there a way to get the number of items I print as a result of a FOR cycle in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, string-length

I have this code:

```
C = 50000
threshold = 0.3
for i in range(1, 18598):
    if binned_orcs[i] > C and ori[i] > threshold: Origins = print(i)
```

I would like to then have a way to know how many items that for cycle with those conditions printed but because every origin is printed on a different line I can't use `len(Origins)` I think, is there a way?

Like the code output is:

```
1875
2550
3424
7426
7498
9065
9866
9924
11828
12116
12334
13317
13788
15110
15348
16988
17185
17572
18516
```

which is 19 numbers and I would like to have a code line which when printed would just give me 19.

Comment: Create a counter an increment it inside the `if` block?

Comment: Just use a counter and +=1 after every iteration. Print the counter instead of whatever you are printing.

Comment: btw, ‘Origins’ is always ‘None’ because print() always returns ‘None’.

Comment: I came here to comment the Origins being None thing. I'm guessing that's a typo and not an actual variable assign (in case the print is actually temporary).

Otherwise, you're probably better off with a generator there, as range is very memory-optimal too ( https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#ranges )

Answer (score 2):

You could add a counter and track the number yourself:

```py
count = 0
for i in range(1, 18598):
    if binned_orcs[i] > C and ori[i] > threshold:
        print(i)
        count += 1

print(count)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also `enumerate` the results and get the last result of the enumerate function. This will work by overriding the value of the counter variable with each loop, relying on a scope *trick*. **Be careful**, as this is something that we usually avoid in python (you won't normally do this **on purpose**)

```py
C = 50000
threshold = 0.3

for num, elem in enumerate(i for i in range(1, 18598)
                           if binned_orcs[i] > C and ori[i] > threshold):
    print(elem)
print(num + 1)
```

Note that I've added 1 to the final sum because it starts on 0, and I'm guessing your count wont. Remove it otherwise.